# Derivative of vector $Q=(x_i-\mu-Lf_i)^t\Psi^{-1}(x_i-\mu-Lf_i)$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectors

Let $x_i$ , $\mu$ and $f_i$ be $p\times 1$ vectors, $L$ and $\Psi$, $p\times p$ matrix where $\Psi$ is diagonal.

If $$Q=(x_i-\mu-Lf_i)^t\Psi^{-1}(x_i-\mu-Lf_i)$$
how I can find $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial f_i}$?

I found a result in a book saying that
$$\hat{f_i}=(L^t\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1}L\Psi^{-1}(x_i-\mu)$$
I tried to found some propertie in matrix coobook to get the derivative, but don't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the double-dot product as a convenient infix notation for the trace, i.e. 
$$\,\,A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
Let's also define two new variables 
$$\eqalign{
 M &= \Psi^{-1} \cr
 v &= (Lf_i + \mu - x_i) \implies dv = L\,df_i \cr
}$$

Then we can write the function, differential, and gradient as 
$$\eqalign{
 Q &= M:vv^T \cr
dQ &= M:(dv\,v^T+v\,dv^T) = (M+M^T)v:dv  \cr
 &= 2Mv:L\,df_i = 2L^TMv:df_i \cr
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial f_i}
 &= 2L^TMv \,\,=\, 2L^T\Psi^{-1}(Lf_i + \mu - x_i) \cr
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve for the minimizer 
$$\eqalign{
 L^T\Psi^{-1}(Lf_i) &= L^T\Psi^{-1}(x_i-\mu) \cr
 f_i &= (L^T\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1}L^T\Psi^{-1}(x_i-\mu) \cr
}$$

Comment: Here $\Phi^{-1}$ is $\Psi^{-1}$ right? You used some property to go from differential to gradient? I mean, looks like the derivative just canceled.

Comment: @Roland Yes, I've replaced all the $\Phi$s with $\Psi$s in my answer. If $g$ is the gradient of $f$ then its differential is $\,\,df=g:dx\,\,$ and vice versa.